# Посчитать соотношение данных за неделю к месяцу

Tags: mysql, sql

Всех приветствую!
Вопрос такой:
текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом
Есть данные по дням dd.mm.yyyy 
Нужно найти соотношение каждой недели месяца (1-5) к этому месяцу отдельно для всего года (соответственно 53 недели *"спасибо за уточнение"*)
Возможен ли какой-то красивый вариант, кроме сложения всех данных по неделям и месяцам и деления друг на друга?

Comment: *соответственно 52 недели* Во-первых, таки 53. Во-вторых, пар (неделя-месяц) больше чем 53. И вообще - лучше выложите CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO с тестовыми данными и дайте эталонный ответ. Ну или создайте online fiddle.